# How to ignore unwanted attributes

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am having an Object (representing a project for example) which implements a tree structure:

```
class Project
{
   data: {};
   children: Array<Project>=[];
}
```

I am using an angular component from Primeng (TreeTable) to visualize this tree and let user dynamically change the tree (Adding children, changing values on data, ...).

This all works fine. But when I send my object using http.post to my backend I get an error (circular values ...). Reason for this is the component from primeng adds additional attributes to my object to manage the tree (parent, expanded, ...). The 'parent' attribute leads to this circular value issue.

Is there a way in typescript to keep my object structure in the context of my application? (Attributes added by the component are not visible to my code and will therefore ignored when using http.post)

Within the http.post function my objects must be changed to json or string. Is there a possibility to overwrite a method which avoid this error? (Like .as_json in rails)

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: can you post whole json, which is being sent to server

Comment: The problem: there is no json sent since system stops with "circular value" error when trying to post the data.

Comment: can you console.log()  the data you are posting and paste it here? Maye the issue is, the data you are posting is not valid a json. And you to make it valid.

Comment: I know why it’s not working - the primeng component add parent reference to each node which makes it cyclic  Therefore my question how can I avoid the added attributes are visible to me or how can I serialise the object myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is caused by a cyclic structure... for example, this is fine:

```
class Project
{
   data: {};
   children: Array<Project>=[];
}

const project = new Project();
project.children.push(new Project());

console.log(JSON.stringify(project));
```

But if you were to add an object to itself, or to one of its children... chaos ensues....

```
class Project
{
   data: {};
   children: Array<Project>=[];
}

const project = new Project();
project.children.push(new Project());

// No problem
console.log(JSON.stringify(project));

project.children.push(project);

// No end!
console.log(JSON.stringify(project));
```

This is a perfectly valid in-memory structure - the reference goes around in circles but ultimately it is *possible*.

When you try to serialize this, it can never reach an end as each time it encounters the original project, it will continue to cycle without end.

## Solution

You will need to map to a non-cyclic type to serialize the data. You can do this with data loss like this:

```
class Project
{
   data: { example: '4'};
   children: Array<Project>=[];
}

const project = new Project();
project.children.push(new Project());

console.log(JSON.stringify(project));

project.children.push(project);

const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet;
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};

JSON.stringify(project, getCircularReplacer());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my issue. I provide the component a copy of my tree structure but with references to the original data hash. Whenever I change the tree structure (adding nodes, deleting nodes etc.) I recalculate a clean tree.

Works - so problem resolved.